# Python error list index out of range when reading from CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

Hey I am trying to read data from a list that is from a CSV file

```
def Load(): #Loads data from the csv that can be stored in functions
global userdata
global user
userdata = []
f = open('userdata.csv','r')
data = csv.reader(f)
for row in data:
    user = []
    for field in row:
        user.append(field)
    userdata.append(user)
f.close()
```

This is the login function which I am looping over

```
def Login(): #Login function
global userdata
Load()
global user
print('Please now login to your account')

x = False
while x == False:
    usernameLog = input('Please enter your username: ')

    j = len(userdata)
    for i in range(0,j):
        if usernameLog == userdata [i][0]: #Validates username
            print('Username accepted')

            time.sleep(1)
```

My program successfully writes to the CSV but just doesn't read from it without throwing out this error. I might just be being stupid though.

Comment: On which line is this error thrown?

Comment: On line 127 IF usernameLog == userdata [i][0]: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: could you please also add a example of the csv?

Comment: Do you mean like: Username: bob and Password: password1?

Comment: The first item in the list is the Username and the second is the password @DanielRodríguez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the line `user = []`  inside the for loop, so you are always "cleaning" user before appending the new value, so only the last value is added, and the previous one is removed.

You should take it out of the loop, the same you are doing with userdata.

(This is what it looks like, unless your csv structure is totally different and you don't need one user per one userdata)

Comment: Thank you that worked. I didn't think it would do that :D